# Vim doesn't flag "int" as a spelling mistake

Tags: spell-checking

I have a file `en.utf-8.add` in the folder of a file being edited by Vim.  I issue `:mkspell! en.utf-8.add` to create a new `en.utf-8.add.spl`.  In the edited document, the word `int` is not flagged as a spelling error.  I also have a `~/.vim/spell/en.utf-8.add` and a corresponding `en.utf-8.add.spl` with the same date/time, but the `en.utf-8.add` also does not contain the word `int`.

**Why is `int` considered correct?  What else can I examine to track down the reason?**

I have `fileencoding=utf-8` and `spellfile=en.utf-8.add`.  I confirmed that the latter takes effect by removing some words and seeing them flagged after the `mkspell! en.utf-8.add` command.  Of course, I add the words back.

Results of `:version` command:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Mar 30 2020 21:51:17)
Included patches: 1-486
Modified by <cygwin@cygwin.com>
Compiled by <cygwin@cygwin.com>
Huge version with GTK3 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static
+arabic            +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       -tcl
+autochdir         +float             +multi_byte        +termguicolors
-autoservername    +folding           +multi_lang        +terminal
+balloon_eval      -footer            -mzscheme          +terminfo
+balloon_eval_term +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
+browse            +gettext           +num64             +textobjects
++builtin_terms    -hangul_input      +packages          +textprop
+byte_offset       +iconv             +path_extra        +timers
+channel           +insert_expand     +perl/dyn          +title
+cindent           +job               +persistent_undo   +toolbar
+clientserver      +jumplist          +popupwin          +user_commands
+clipboard         +keymap            +postscript        +vartabs
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           +profile           +virtualedit
+cmdline_info      +libcall           +python/dyn        +visual
+comments          +linebreak         +python3/dyn       +visualextra
+conceal           +lispindent        +quickfix          +viminfo
+cryptv            +listcmds          +reltime           +vreplace
+cscope            +localmap          +rightleft         +wildignore
+cursorbind        +lua/dyn           +ruby/dyn          +wildmenu
+cursorshape       +menu              +scrollbind        +windows
+dialog_con_gui    +mksession         +signs             +writebackup
+diff              +modify_fname      +smartindent       +X11
+digraphs          +mouse             +sound             -xfontset
+dnd               +mouseshape        +spell             +xim
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +startuptime       +xpm
+emacs_tags        -mouse_gpm         +statusline        +xsmp_interact
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      +xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "/etc/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/etc"
 f-b for $VIMRUNTIME: "/usr/share/vim/vim82"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/dbus-1.0/include -D_REENTRANT    -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/vim/vim-8.2.0486-1.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/vim-8.2.0486-1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/vim/vim-8.2.0486-1.x86_64/src/vim-8.2.0486=/usr/src/debug/vim-8.2.0486-1 -fstack-protector-strong -D_REENTRANT  -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -L. -fstack-protector-strong  -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim.exe   -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl  -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm    -lncursesw -lcanberra  -liconv -lacl -lattr -lintl   -Wl,--enable-auto-import -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -fstack-protector-strong  -L/usr/lib/perl5/5.30/x86_64-cygwin-threads/CORE -lperl -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a few dictionaries I checked, `int` is an abbreviation for numerous words such as international and internal.  vim considers it "local" or "regional."

For me, `int` *is* in the main vim listed by `:spellinfo`;

```
file: `/usr/share/vim/vim82/spell/en.utf-8.spl`
```

You can see this using `:spelldump` which says `int/13`, meaning it is considered valid in the US and Canada.

If you want it to mark this as a wrong word, just use `zw` on top of the word.

Comment: Egad.  Those two commands are so useful.  `:spelldump` shows `int/13`. The help for `spell-wordlist-format` provides the example that `blah/12` is for regions `us` and `ca`, but it isn't clear where the enumerations are defined.  Ah well, I'm miles ahead of where I was.  Thanks!

Comment: The regions mapping is listed at the top of `spelldump`; `/regions=usaucagbnz` (every 2 letters map to numbers 1-5) which means this word is considered good for `us` and `ca`.  If you were to set your region otherwise, via e.g., `set spelllang=en_nz` then this word would be highlighted for being "local."

Comment: Thanks again, Mass.  This has been a good reminder that there is a lot of sophistication behind the scenes to make Vim so useful.  There's no free lunch, but in this case, it's worth the price.